# OctoberCMS installation MYSQL error

Tags: php, mysql, octobercms, octobercms-backend, laragon

I am getting the following error while installing OctoberCMS in Laragon Apache while either using the wizard or the Artisan CLI...

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of '.\...\#sql-1114_c' to '.\...\system_event_logs' (errno: 13 "Permission denied") (SQL: ALTER TABLE system_event_logs MODIFY `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL)
```

Could someone help with this? It is the latest OctoberCMS.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like an issue with databse user permissions. Can you confirm that the db user has all the required privileges?

Comment: Hi @dragontree. Thank you. The database does have the permissions as installing Wordpress using the same database user and permissions was successful.

Comment: I believe WordPress just uses the SELECT, CREATE, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions. October uses more than WordPress as it supports migrations (files that change the structure of the database) and such will often use commands such as ALTER. Make sure your provided DB user has full permissions on the database you are trying to use with October otherwise you will run into problems.

Comment: Thank you @LukeTowers. Will have a look at where they are configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LukeTowers said, this must be a permissions issue.

> (errno: 13 "Permission denied")

is a big clue :)
Ensure user has all privileges and permissions and your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out it might be a shared host restriction. Migrating to dedicated host resolves it though I am not sure why they have it on Softaculous.